# Show that $\mathbb Z$ with operation $•$, $a•b =a+b$ if $a$ is even ; $a•b =a-b$ if $a$ is odd is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

Suppose that $•$ is the operation defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ by:

1. $a • b = a + b$ if $a$ is even.
2. $a • b = a-b$ if $a$ is odd.

Prove that it is a group.

---

Closure: if $a,b\in (\mathbb{Z}, •)$ $\implies$ $a • b\in(\mathbb{Z} •)$;

Associative: $a • (b • c) = (a • b) • c$, $\forall$ $a, b, c \in (\mathbb{Z}, •)$, therefore

$$a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$$

$$a- (b-c) = (a-b) -c$$
for all integers.

Identity element: $0$

$a • 0 = a + 0 =a$
$a • 0 = a - 0 = a$

Inverse element: $-a$ or $a$

$a • -a = a + (- a) = 0 $
$a•a =a-a = 0$

I ask if the demonstration is acceptable and some advice to improve it.
Thanks so much.

Comment: the associative property needs more to be proved. Notice that the four operations can be different, even in the same expression

Comment: and also you have to prove that $0$ is a left identity

Comment: and, by the way $(a-b) - c \ne a - (b-c)$

Comment: Associativity is an issue as said.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof for closure is fine. Essentially, there is nothing to show.

For associativity, it is not clear what you have tried to do, but as things stand you have not proved that the operation is associative. You must separately consider $4$ different cases: one for each possibility where $a$ and $b$ are even or odd. For instance, in the case where $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, we have
$$
a \bullet(b \bullet c) = a \bullet (b + c) = a - (b + c) = a - b - c\\
(a \bullet b) \bullet c = \underbrace{(a - b)}_{\text{this is odd!}} \bullet c = (a - b) - c = a - b - c.
$$
For the identity element, you must show that we have both $a \bullet 0 = a$ **and** $0 \bullet a = a$.

For the inverse element, you must clarify that $a$ is the inverse of $a$ in the case that $a$ is even, and $-a$ is the inverse of $a$ in the case that $a$ is odd.

---

For another way to see that $\bullet$ is a group operation, note that
$$
a \bullet b = a + (-1)^a b.
$$
Thinking of a $a$ as the map $f_a: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ defined by $f_a(x) = a + (-1)^a x$ allows us to identify $(\Bbb Z,\bullet)$ with a subset of the invertible maps over $\Bbb Z$. To see that this subset is a subgroup, it suffices to verify that the subset is closed under composition and inverses. For closure under composition, note that
$$
(f_a \circ f_b)(x) = a + (-1)^a(b + (-1)^bx) 
\\ = (a + (-1)^ab) + (-1)^{a + b}x\\
\\ = f_{a + (-1)^ab}(x),
$$
which is a map of the desired form.

Interestingly, once we prove that $\bullet$ is a group operation in this way, we can say that
$$
(f_a \circ f_b)(x) = f_a(b \bullet x) = a \bullet (b \bullet x) = (a \bullet b)\bullet x = f_{a \bullet b}(x).
$$
That is, if the image of $(\Bbb Z,\bullet)$ in $S_\Bbb Z$ under $a \mapsto f_a$ yields a subgroup, the associativity of $\bullet$ follows.

---

For my own curiosity, the question of identifying the group:

We see that $a^2 = 0$ whenever $a$ is odd.  Also, we note that all even elements can be written as $2k = 2^{\bullet k}$.  Finally, we note that
$$
2 \bullet 1 = 2 + 1 = 3.
$$
In other words,
$$
(\Bbb Z, \bullet) = \langle 1,2 \mid 1^{\bullet 2} = (1 \bullet 2)^{\bullet 2} = 0 \rangle.
$$
That is, $(\Bbb Z, \bullet)$ is the [infinite dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group).

It would be interesting to produce a direct isomorphism between $\{f_a : a \in \Bbb Z\}$ an the [isometry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_group) of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks so much! For the identity element, I had to show that a = even a ∙ 0 = 0 • a = 0 that is, a + 0 = 0 + a = a a = odd a ∙ 0 = 0 • a = 0 i.e. a-0 = 0 - (- a) = a while for the inverse element a = even then the inverse element is -a a • -a = a + (- a) = 0 a = odd then the inverse element is a • to a = a-a = 0 The associativity instead must be verified for the four cases: even - even even-odd odd-even (that's what you've already shown me;) odd-odd Thanks again

Comment: Your comments are very interesting, but I have some doubts when you say .... "Thinking of a as                            the map f_a: Z → Z defined by f_a (x) = a + (- 1) ^ ax allows us to identify (Z, ∙) with a subset of the invertible maps over Z ", what do you mean? I saw that staring" a ", even or odd with x belongs to Z, the map generates Z. Thanks so much

Comment: @MARCUSTITO Perhaps you have seen the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $S_n$, which is the set of invertible functions from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1,\dots,n\}$ under the binary operation of function composition. Likewise, the set of invertible functions from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$ (sometimes denoted $S_\infty$) is a group.

Comment: @MARCUSTITO Note that the function $f:(\Bbb Z, \bullet) \to S_\infty$ defined by $f(a) = f_a$ is injective. In other words, each $a \in \Bbb Z$ corresponds to a unique element (that is, a unique *function*) of $S_\infty$. From there, perhaps the rest makes more sense.

Comment: Starting from thinking of a as the map f_a: Z → Z defined by f_a (x) = a + (- 1) ^ ax how do I prove the closure under inveses

Comment: @MARCUSTITO We have
$$
y = a + (-1)^a x \implies x = (-1)^a(y-a) = 
\begin{cases}
(-a) + (-1)^{-a}y & a \text{ is even}\\
a + (-1)^ay & a \text{is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$
So, noting that $x = f^{-1}_a(y)$ above, we see that $f_a^{-1}$ is indeed a map of the required form.